# Pandas DataFrame Scalar Values Index Pass

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a linear regression test where I am trying to compare the test results in a table. With my current setup I am receiving an error `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`, which I feel is related to the varying data formats of the values being stored in the DataFrame. What is the proper format I should be using to achieve this comparison table?

Here is my code:

```
print(type(y_test))
print(type(y_pred))

print(y_test)
print(y_pred)

# compare predictions to actuals
df_full_results = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred})

# display results as table
display(HTML(df_full_results.to_html()))
```

Here is the code triggering the error:

```
df_full_results = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred})
```

Here is the output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

 b_leads
214      11
148       7
227       9
131      14
....

[63 rows x 1 columns]
[[14.03709801]
 [ 6.58161653]
 [13.02991554]
....
```

Comment: which line triggers the error message?

Comment: You are trying to set one of the column of your `DataFrames` to be another `DataFrame`. I don't think this is possible, or should ever be done... Likely you want `'Actual': y_test.values.tolist()`

Comment: @Yuca `df_full_results = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred})`

Comment: @ALollz good call. I tried your solution, but receive an error `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing what you're putting into the DataFrame into a variable instead, and then put it into the df_full_results.  In example;

```
data_stuff = {'Actual': y_test,
              'Predicted': y_pred
             }
df_full_results = pd.DataFrame(data_stuff, columns=['Actual', 'Predicted'])
```